# Combobox SelectedItem is not working in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, winui-3

I have a Combobox with some items, i fill combobox this way:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(Constants.TranslationsPath);
var items = new ObservableCollection<Translation>();
using var db = new AlAnvarDBContext();
if (files.Count() > 0)
 {
   foreach (var file in files)
   {
     var id = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
     var trans = db.Translations.Where(x => x.Link.Contains(id)).FirstOrDefault();
     if (trans != null)
     {
      items.Add(trans);
     }
   }
   cmbTranslators.ItemsSource = items;
   cmbTranslators.SelectedItem = Settings.DefaultTranslation;
 }
```

and xaml:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbTranslators">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="table:Translation">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="-"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Language}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="-"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Translator}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
```

The problem is that the default item (SelectedItem) is not selected and i need to select default item in combobox.

Comment: What is the `Settings.DefaultTranslation` object? Is it a ComboBoxItem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cmbTranslators.SelectedItem = cmbTranslators.Items.Where(x=>((Translation)x).Id == Settings.DefaultTranslation.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the `Settings.DefaultTranslation` is not equal to any of the `items` in the item collection and that is why the assignment did not occur? Maybe you can add it to your collection `Settings.DefaultTranslation` like the first element and set `cmbTranslators.SelectedIndex = 0`